# add contents through textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application which contain a textbox (`tbox`) and two buttons: Save (`b1`) and Delete (`b2`) and an XML file `leaf.xml`

Whenever i am putting anything in textbox and then click Save (`b1`) the content in textbox will be saved in the `leaf.xml` file. When i press delete (`b2`), it will delete from the file `leaf.xml` and at the same time it will disable the Save button.

this is the xml file wahatever adding will come to  tag,suppose if we add test it will
come as

`<Name>test</Name>`

Comment: I couldn;t begin to think of answer without knowing the Xml structure, do you want to add nodes to it, overwrite the entire file, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: yes i want to add nodes in to it

Comment: then show us a part of your xml..

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to look at the [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).  It will let you serialize/deserialize your "ObjectClass" to/from a stream.  Likewise, you probably want to look at the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class, for opening file streams (to pass into the XMLSerializer) and delete files (File.Delete).

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to do that....see code below:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("People.xml"));

xmlDoc.Element("Persons").Add(new XElement("Person", new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
new XElement("City", txtCity.Text), new XElement("Age", txtAge.Text)));

xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("People.xml"));
lblStatus.Text = "Data successfully added to XML file.";
```

Answer (score -1):

The save should be something like this, the delete works with XPath (find the Name element that has the supplied text in it, then delete it, save the file again.)

This will not work if any person with the same name is entered off course...

```
Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FileStream fs = new FileStream("leaf.xml",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(fs);
  XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("","Name","");
  XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(textbox1.Text);
  elem.AppendChild(text);
  doc.RootNode.AppendChild(elem);

  doc.Save("leaf.xml");
}
```

Comment: Sorry... Nobody should ever be using the XmlDocument for this type of work unless they are working on legacy code.  There are so many other ways to do this, and the XmlDocument is the worst for many reasons.  At least use the XDocument in place of the XmlDocument...

Comment: I agree, this is something I wrote down to point the OP in a direction. He is clearly new at this...

Comment: i am getting this error 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'RootNode'

Comment: sorry, it should be FirstChild